# Parse Promise not being called when one line is uncommented

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve the id of a object in my user class. Basically the structure is I have a game class which has a pointer to a game session class and in the game session I have a pointer to the user. I need to grab the user object id, but when I add the line to get the id of the user, the parse promise does not get called, but when I uncomment the line it does get called.

```
      var game = Parse.Object.extend("Game");
      var query = new Parse.Query(game);
      query.include("GameSession");
      query.include("GameSession.User");

      query.each((game) => {
        var gamesession = game.get("GameSession");
        var userid = gamesession.get("User").id;
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("called"); //prints when I comment the var userid line, but does not print when I uncomment that line.
      })
```

Comment: Add a `.catch` after your `.then`. There's probably an error being thrown in the callback to `each` that you're not handling.

Comment: Yup it is telling me that `gamesession.get is not a function`, but I included `GameSession.User`

Comment: What is `session.get`?